# hist 2 variable with different x value

Tags: r, graph, histogram

I have a data frame 'TOT', with the value of abundance of a species and values of temperature, something like this:

```
AB_specie    : int  2 1 11 1 6 2 1 8 1 3 

TEMP          : num  24.8 21 24.8 25.6 24.8 ..


structure(list(AB_specie = c(2L, 1L, 11L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 65L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 16L,1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L,2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L), TEMP = c(24.8332,20.9689, 24.7757, 25.648, 24.7579, 25.2056, 25.6153,23.1105,25.0967, 25.0202, 23.4963, 24.9033, 25.0009, 25.1767, 24.6222,26.5870991, 24.9885006,26.8768997, 25.2455006, 25.8085995, 26.8239002,26.6907997, 27.2084007, 27.2700005, 27.1746998, 27.2026005, 25.3586006,25.4300003, 24.9193001, 27.0338001, 23.0319004, 26.4820995, 25.2614994,27.2424, 27.664, 27.4767, 27.4602, 26.3897, 24.5804, 26.9536,26.3928, 26.1778, 27.1487, 26.3726, 26.6156, 26.5343, 23.7879,24.6767, 26.834, 26.9746)), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to hist the frequency of temperature, and see how the frequency of abundance of the species overlaps. To understand at what temperatures I have more abundance of the species

I did this :

```
hist(TOT$AB_specie, breaks=30, xlim=c(0,15), col=rgb(1,0,0,0.5), xlab="", 
 ylab="FREQUENCY", main="" )
hist(TOT$TEMP, breaks=30, xlim=c(0,15), col=rgb(0,0,1,0.5), add=T)
legend("topright", legend=c("AB_specie","TEMP"), col=c(rgb(1,0,0,0.5), 
                                                  rgb(0,0,1,0.5)), pt.cex=2, pch=15 )
```

But obviously, having two different values of x, I get something like this
[image]

can you help me understand how I can graph this information? Excuse me, I'm a beginner

And this is what I have with scatterplot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keiCM.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keiCM.jpg)

Comment: Please add sample data to the question using `dput(head(TOT,n))` where n is the number of rows you find sufficient for reproducibility. You can copy and paste the output to your question for better reproducibility.

Comment: Why not a scatterplot `TEMP` versus `AB_specie`?

Comment: I did this: plot(TOT$AB_species, TOT$TEMP, main="Scatterplot Example", 
     xlab="AB_species ", ylab="TEMP ", pch=19, xlim=c(0,31))
attach(TOT)
abline(lm(TEMP ~AB_species), col="red") # regression line (y~x) 
lines(lowess(AB_species,TEMP), col="blue") # lowess line (x,y)
detach(TOT)

Comment: So you "did" that. Was that a satisfactory solution?

Comment: Yes, thank you. Unfortunately, there is no good correlation between the two variable